# Какие приемущества и недостатки при использовании этих библиотек для OAuth?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth

[DevDefined.OAuth](http://code.google.com/p/devdefined-tools/wiki/OAuth)

[Madgex OAuth.Net](http://lab.madgex.com/oauth-net/)

[DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/)